# Expected value of conditional events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

This question is in continuation to:
[Obtaining binomial distribution from normal distribution, and repeated events.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3223846/obtaining-binomial-distribution-from-normal-distribution-and-repeated-events/3223976#3223976)

Let us consider a random variable, $x$ chosen from a normal distribution. Define, $x \leq 4$ as event A. We are given with pdf of occurrence of a second event B, $P(B/A)$. Literally, event B here indicates whether the player has lost or not. It is imminent, the probability of occurrence of B relies on the state of event A. The question is to calculate the expected total loss. However, I am confused about whether to use conditional, Baysean probability, $P(A/B)$, or $P(A \cap B)$ to calculate expectation.

N.B.: Literally, In a cricket match, event A is one of the possible moves taken up by the fielding team (in a cricket match). The batsman has a set of moves, and, batsman's strategy relies on the move taken up by the fielding team. Say, $B$ is the set of moves that beats him (or, incurs some cost $\mathcal{C}$), i.e., $P(B/A)$ is known. $\mathcal{C}$ is a constant. I need to calculate the expected number of times the batsman is lost and the incurred cost.

Comment: You need to distinguish events and random variables: events have probabilities, random variables don't; events don't have distribution, variables do. Formally, event is some set of elementary outcomes, and rv is function on elementary outcomes. Are $A$ and $B$ events or rv? Do you need expectation of $A$ and $B$ (it can't be defined - either you can't say "$A$ and $B$", or can't say "expectation of it") or probability?

Comment: @mihaild the question is updated now.

Comment: @George Dewhirst Please look into this problem.