# Expected value of conditional probability event

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, expected-value

This is in continuation to [Expected value of conditional events](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3224233/expected-value-of-conditional-events?noredirect=1#comment6633574_3224233)

In a cricket match, event A is a subset of all possible moves taken up by the fielding team. The batsman has a set of moves, and, batsman's strategy relies on the move taken up by the fielding team. Say, $B$ is the set of moves that defeats him (or, incurs some cost $\mathcal{C}$), i.e., $P(B/A)$ is known. $\mathcal{C}$ is a constant.

Let $A$ and $\bar{A}$ be the set of event chosen by the fielding side. And $B$ and $\bar{B}$ be the set of moves pursued by the batsman. Then all possible event combinations will be,
$A \cap B$, $A \cap \bar{B}$, $\bar{A} \cap B$ and $\bar{A} \cap \bar{B}$. Given the problem, the associated probabilities calculated as, $P(B/A)P(A)$, $P(\bar{B}/A)P(A)$, $P(B/\bar{A})P(\bar{A})$ and $P(\bar{B}/\bar{A})P(\bar{A})$ respectively.

The batsman is willing to know the expected total cost s/he might incur if the fielding team chooses the strategy-set $A$.Batsman does not care about $\bar{A}$.

The expected cost incurred will be:
$\mathcal{C}\left( 1 \times P(B/A)P(A) + 0 \times P(\bar{B}/A)P(A) + 0 \times P(B/\bar{A})P(\bar{A}) + 0 \times P(\bar{B}/\bar{A})P(\bar{A}) \right)$

Is my argument alright?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question. As I understand it, the batsman will incur a cost of $\mathcal{C}$ if he chooses a strategy in $B$ and the fielding team takes up a strategy in $A$. Is there a cost to taking up strategy $\overline{B}$ when the fielding side uses strategy $\overline{A}$? Also, you want to know the expected cost if the fielding team chooses a strategy in $A$? It looks like you calculated the expected cost incurred by the batter as a result of the fielding team choosing strategy $A$ rather than the expected cost if the fielding team chooses strategy $A$.